# 'Independence between the hands' - express this better

Tags: vocabulary

I teach people how to play the piano.  I have also published a couple of books that help absolute beginners to get started.  One of the major challenges that piano players encounter is playing simultaneously different patterns with each hand.

Developing this pianistic skill is a major purpose of one of my books. In the blurb about the book I say that the exercises and pieces it contains  help students develop *independence between their hands*. Although this description does work for me, I have often wondered whether it can be said better.

Comment: Not what is asked, strictly speaking, but for the context, *ambidexterity* could be a good choice. Ambidexterity wouldn't be possible without the two hands working independently (actually, in this case, in co-ordination without "mirroring.")

Comment: @Kris - Thanks for this. I have wondered about ambidextrous. I don't think it quite covers the idea of being able to use both hands at the same time. Does being able to (for example) write equally well with either hand suggest that you can, as well, write your first name using a pen in your right hand while, simultaneously, you write your surname with a pen in your left?!

Comment: You are of course, right. See "Ambidexterity" on Wikipedia esp. in relation to Sports and to Music -- that's an altogether different kind of animal, and I was aware of that.

Comment: This might be a question better suited for a [music group](http://music.stackexchange.com/), if you want to know what the musician's jargon is for this.

Comment: Just 'dexterity'?

Comment: I'd like to say yes.  Lovely word... but the OED describes dexterity as "manual or manipulative skill, adroitness, neat-handedness", which is close but not really talking about the hands/fingers doing different things at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hand differentiation?

This question on [music.stackexchange.com](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/3215/how-can-i-significantly-improve-my-hand-independence-on-piano) uses just "hand independence" and that seems to be well understood.

This piano company's [website](http://www.roland.co.uk/blog/piano-lessons-hand-and-finger-independence/) refers to it as "hand and finger independence", although that sounds like the hand is independent from the fingers.

I think it doesn't help to overthink it--"independence between the hands" or the (apparently) simpler and more common "hand independence" both seem clear enough to me for regular usage.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ideas. You could say your book helps students develop **hand independence** (notice the difference - not *between* their hands). I'm pretty sure that's what most people say. Maybe the term **autonomy** helps you too.

Either way, I suppose you can't be as precise as you'd like to without using a more scientific approach, as suggested above (*bimanual independence*).

Comment: *Hand independence* is a strong contender - but it doesn't, on its own, emphasise the idea that the 'independence' is from (?) the other hand!

Comment: You're right, but this could lead to an argument over the very idea that the OP's trying to find a word for and what it actually means. I, as a guitarist, consider that it's not a matter of _hand independence_ (or whatever you'd like to call it, hehe) but actually hand coordination. Both hands must in fact be dependent on each other but the player must be able to coordinate them freely. That's just my take on it, though.

Comment: Good point @Fausto NA  - of course the two hands have to work together.  The purpose of the practice however is to help beginners to process simultaneously two distinct patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that your book will help students **develop bimanual independence** or **reduce bimanual interference**.

Comment: Hmm ...  This is, quite possibly, *clinically* accurate.  I'm hoping for a more everyday turn of phrase/idiom.

Comment: @Dan His response is correct, though in normal speach you would just say bimanual.

Comment: *Bimanual* on its own is just (only just!) the right side (for me) of medical geekiness.  The problem is that according to OED 'bimanual' means   *performed with both hands; in which both hands are employed*.  This does not answer the need for two hands making different patterns simulataneously.  *Bimanual independence* probably does fit the bill - except that its too scientific...

Answer (score 1):

In that context, **independence** is clearly the right word. The term is used referring to other instruments as well, e.g. drums, where independence is critical.

E.g. "These are exercises to help you gain independence between all of your limbs." - http://www.chellman.org/drums/extreme/

E.g. A lesson in "[Essential Jazz Independence](http://www.bangthedrumschool.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/essential-jazz-independence-part-one.pdf)" from the [Bang Drum School](http://www.bangthedrumschool.com/9-essential-jazz-independence-exercises/).

I've heard the word **autonomy** used as well, but can't remember where (besides in @Fausto NA's answer)

Answer (score 0):

I find that "independence of hands" works better than "independence between hands".  You might also try "decoupling the hands" but it sounds a bit like electronic circuitry.

By the way, you might generally consider using "the hands" instead of just "hands": it strongly suggests that you are talking about the left hand and the right hand (which play different assigned roles for the piano) rather than just any two hands (like when using hammer and chisel which you can swap).

Answer (score 0):

The words 'independence of hands' is a good choice. I think it is more engaging to address your potential buyers as 'you' and then they perceive how you can help 'them' - rather than it being an abstract problem that they may not as yet perceive their connection with.  So you could say 'Improves how you use your hands independently' rather than the abstract (and rather dry!) 'enhances hand independence.'

How about 'helps you overcome the challenge of using your hands (independently) to play two different things at the same time.' Or 'helps with right and left hand co-ordination.'

You could have a heading 'does the left hand know what the right hand is doing? And under it put 'quickly master left and right hand co-ordination with a special technique that...'

Very new students may not even be aware of that 'problem' yet.

I suggest personalising it by saying 'your hands' not 'the hands'. And saying 'you can' instead of 'students can.'

Unless.. your audience is music teachers.

And explain *the benefit* - eg 'enabling you to play the bass line and melody together, with ease' (or whatever it is) - 'enabling you to master more complex tunes quickly and easily' or 'enabling you to quickly sound like a real musician' or whatever you perceive your reader's goal to be.

'Helps you easily learn to co-ordinate your hands to play two different things at once.'